# How do I restrict user log ins to only a specific set of computers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-server-2012

I want to restrict user admin access with regards to their department.
I want to give access to users in Security Group A to computers in Security Group B and i want to create similar access for 9 departments.

I want to restrict this with Group policy so that if anyone adds users for local admins it would wipe out with policy refresh.

I am setting up a new W2012 R2 environment and need help for the same.
Any help is appreciated.

thanks,
Pasha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to be very careful using this.  Make sure to test it in your test OU.

There is a Computer side policy for local logins.  Computer->Policies->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Local Policies->User Rights Assignment: Allow log on locally.  You would want to add Security Group A to that and assign the GPO to an OU with the computer from Security Group B.  You can either create an OU or put them in a group and use security filtering on the GPO.

You would also want to require ctrl+alt+del for logon.  That is under: Computer->Policies->Windows Settings->Security Settings->Local Policies->Security Options: Interactive logon: Do not require ctrl+alt+del set to Disable.